# Short story with a alien planet, government officials must wear exploding medallions

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Can someone please help me identify the short story where, on some alien planet, every government official must wear a medallion that explodes, on his/her neck. The explosion is triggered when a citizen who is unhappy about this particular official pushes a button in a special booth in the street.

In the story one such official, who expects his medallion to be triggered to explode soon, tricks a tourist or a traveler into wearing the medallion in his stead after renting out his flat to the traveler.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is an interesting question, but you might be able to improve it by checking out [the suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking a good question.  Maybe you can add when and where you read it?

Comment: @DavidW They're asking because they didn't know.

Comment: @SamJakob There are things they know they know, and things they know they don't know.  There are also things they don't know they know, and things they don't know they don't know. :)

Comment: "In the story one such official, who expects his medallion to be triggered to explode soon, tricks a tourist or a traveler into wearing the medallion in his stead after renting out his flat to the traveler." It's more accurate to say he attempts to trick. It doesn't actually happen.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sounds like [*A Ticket to Tranai*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45874) ([text of story](https://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/149381/8/Sheckley_-_Citizen_in_Space.html)) by Robert Sheckley.

It contains all the elements you mention:

1. The main character travels to the planet in question (Tranai) and is offered to become Supreme President.
2. The Supreme President has an official medallion around his neck.
3. Said medallion explodes if enough people press a button in a public booth to express their disapproval of the president's policies.

It first appeared in *Galaxy*, October 1955, but has been reprinted in several anthologies and collections.